# In wso2 dropbox connector how do you upload a file conector

Tags: wso2-esb

In wso2 dropbox connector how do you upload a file connector.  Can you tell me the details about uploading a connector into dropbox connector

Comment: Sorry this question is not clear. Can you provide more details of the use case?

Comment: can you tell me the procedure of doing upload file  in dropbox connector using wso2

Answer (score 1):

Enable the following message builders and formatters in axis2 configuration file.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/octet-stream" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="application/octet-stream" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

You can use the proxy service mentioned in [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-dropbox/blob/master/src/test/resources/artifacts/ESB/config/proxies/dropbox/dropbox.xml) and use the following curl command with your credentials.

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8280/services/dropbox?apiUrl=https://api-content.dropbox.com&accessToken=XcXXXXXXXdPkM2hL-wb9F&root=dropbox&path=fileconnector-connector-2.0.4.zip&locale=fr-FR&overwrite=true&contentLength=3' -H 'Action: urn:uploadFile' -F file=@/path/to/a/fileconnector-connector-2.0.4.zip
```